# aesimc instruction gives incorrect result

Tags: c++, aes, encryption, instruction-set, machine-instruction

I'm trying to implement AES cryptography using the AES machine instructions (basing it on Intel's [white paper](http://software.intel.com/file/24917)) available on my Sandy Bridge. Unfortunately, I've come to a halt in the phase of generating the round keys for decryption. Specifically, the instruction `aesimc` (applying the *Inverse Mix Columns* operation) returns an incorrect result.

In their paper they have an example:
[image]

So with input:

```
48 69 28 53 68 61 79 29 5B 47 75 65 72 6F 6E 5D
```

I get the following using `_mm_aesimc_si128()`:

```
2D BF F9 31 99 CD 3A 37 B7 C7 81 FD 7D E0 3D 8E
```

It should have returned:

```
62 7A 6F 66 44 B1 09 C8 2B 18 33 0A 81 C3 B3 E5
```

Not the same result. **Why is this the case?**

If you want to reproduce it, I tested it with the code below (remember the arguments `-maes -msse4` when compiling):

```
#include <wmmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_m128i(__m128i data) {
  unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char*) &data;
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    int val = (int) ptr[i];
    if (val < 0xF) {
      cout << "0";
    }    
    cout << uppercase << hex << val << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}

int main() {
  unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*)
    "\x48\x69\x28\x53\x68\x61\x79\x29\x5B\x47\x75\x65\x72\x6F\x6E\x5D";
  __m128i num = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) data);
  __m128i num2 = _mm_aesimc_si128(num);
  print_m128i(num2);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** The example in Intel's white paper was wrong. As Hans suggested, my chip is little-endian so byte-swapping is necessary - to and fro.

Comment: Because that looks like a C-string, I assume the compiler includes a trailing `'\0'` ascii NUL in `data`. Does `__mm_loadu_si128()` read exactly the correct length? (I expect it does, but I've been wrong when making assumptions before. ;) Furthermore, the string pointed to by `data` may be 4-aligned or 8-aligned, but these instructions _feel_ like they require 16-aligned memory.

Comment: Good point. :) `_mm_loadu_si128()` doesn't require a 16-aligned address (hence the 'u'), `_mm_load_si128` does however. It reads exactly 128 bits. But I tried aligning it anyway with `unsigned char *data __attribute__((aligned(16))) = ..` and it didn't change the result unfortunately.

Comment: darn -- thanks for the quick feedback. :)

Comment: Their example might be wrong, see if this works: InvMixColumns (8dcab9dc035006bc8f57161e00cafd8d) = d635a667928b5eaeeec9cc3bc55f5777

Comment: Oh, if I take your input vector and reverse it (little endian): 8D FD CA 00 1E 16 57 8F BC 06 50 03 DC B9 CA 8D, it yields 77 57 5F C5 3B CC C9 EE AE 5E 8B 92 67 A6 35 D6. But reversing that actually gives D6 35 A6 67 92 8B 5E AE EE C9 CC 3B C5 5F 57 77.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytes are backwards.  You want 0x5d to be the least significant byte, it has to come first.  This is a little-endian chip.  In VS, use Debug + Windows + Registers, right-click + tick SSE to see the register values.

Comment: Interesting point, I forgot about endianness. So you mean I should use `"\x5D\x6E\x6F\x72\x65\x75\x47\x5B\x29\x79\x61\x68\x53\x28\x69\x48"` as `data` instead? If so I get the result: B6 59 D8 19 A1 C5 9B F3 15 AA EF 09 F1 8D 7F 59. And that isn't the correct result either.

Comment: Well, that's why they call it cryptography.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, it's quite weird. I've inspected the values of the registers `xmm0` and `xmm1` (in GDB) with `0x5D` both as the least and most significant byte (along with the rest of the data, of course). Well, both are wrong for some reason.

Comment: your answer is correct. I forgot to swap the byte-order back after applying the operation (on the byte-swapped input).